# Does website like wix or weebly are multisites system?

Tags: web-hosting

I'd like to know how websites like wix.com or weebly.com are hosted?

Does each website build on their system are hosted independently? Or are they sharing the same code like a Wordpress multisite system?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

WIX is a bit like wordpress. Your code will be generated by referencing templates that they have created. Then when you are editing it, you are pretty much just changing the CSS. Even adding new items on the page etc is just adding another div for that element, that you then style with CSS.

If you look at the source code of the pages its quite ugly, because all the styles are mostly hard coded and not fluid. But hats off to them for creating such an easy system that's so easy to use.

A wix site relies on their systems so you can never self host it. Unless you want to get hacky with fairly unmanageable code, due to not having their editor.